# How to copy all the content of an EC2 server to OSX

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance I"m trying to copy all the data inside of it into my drive.
the command 
"scp -r / /users/seraph/targetdirectory" 
does not work and returns 
"no such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

On the *OS X* machine:

```
scp -r remotehost:/ /some/local/path
```

Better yet, use rsync so that you can support resume and deltas:

```
rsync -e ssh -avz remotehost:/ /some/local/path
```